# How to save rich text with images and display it on a Text View?

Tags: java, android

I have some rich text, with images, that need to be saved to the device, so that its images can be displayed offline. How to I do that?

Comment: What did you try??

Comment: You should probably elaborate a little on what rich text means in this case. html? rtf? pdf? How are you accessing it? (Some sort of API I'd assume)

Comment: I'm using html. I've tried some implementations on the forum, taking the images from the html and downloading them, but they are mostly outdated,